# Div not fitting in Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to simply insert a Div in a div! but its not working!
Its showing it outside the Div?

Output:
[image]

Html:

```
 echo "<br>
        <div class='data_block'>
        <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $row['ar_image'] )."' class='data_image'/>
        <div class='data_title'>". $row['ar_title']."</div>
        <div class='data_desc'>".$row['ar_desc']."</div>
        </div>";
```

CSS:

```
.data_title
{
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    font-weight:600;
    float: right; 
    width:500px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

.data_desc
{
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o6es4msg/ here it is

Comment: I don't see the issue in the fiddle...

Comment: @Zak it is showing outside the grey block.. the desc should be shown in the grey block below the title..! See my image output! fiddle is showing it properly but not my webpage!

Comment: @ThesK Which browser are you testing your code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed your widths and just floated the text right. I also put your text into paragraph tags. Had to adjust the margin-right on the description to get in inline with the title. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0t0boc70/)

```css
.data_block {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.data_image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.data_desc {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: -60px;
}
.data_title p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='data_block'>
  <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $row[' ar_image '])"' class='data_image' />
  <div class='data_title'>
    <p>gdfgdf</p>
  </div>
  <div class='data_desc'>
    <p>fhdhfisdhfi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I included the bare minimum to make it work, it might not be exactly what you need, but it should point you to the right direction.

I also changed some html tags to make it more semantic

HTML:

```
<div class='data-block cf'>
    <img class="data-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="image" />
    <h2 class='data-title'>Title here</h2>
    <p class='data-desc'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam veniam ipsa, ea nostrum eos possimus eaque accusantium deserunt quod!</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.data-block {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden; /* To make the border radius work */
}

.data-image {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.data-title {
  width: clac(100% - 200px); /* 200px is the image */
  text-align: center;
}

.data-desc {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  /* 200px is the image,
     if you set a smaller width other than 100% remember to compensate with:
     margin-left: (your-width / 2) */
  float: left
}

/* clearfix from http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rzq9q1q/)